# how to create version one burned down chart using java REST client api

Tags: api, rest, agile, versionone

I am trying to get the data to create the burned down chart from version one.
I came to know there is no standard api's for that.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956826/how-do-i-use-the-version-one-api-to-get-project-and-sprint-burndown-charts/24015108#24015108) i found that by making multiple call's to fetch todo value for a scope of timebox it is possible.

Is there any better way to do it?
and also let me know any good open source libraries(javascrpt/java) to plot such graph

i tried the way shown [here](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Sample_Code/Query_for_Burndown_Data) but i am not able to make out what value i am getting.

i tried a get request like

> "base URL"/rest-1.v1/Data/Timebox?where=State.Code='ACTV'&asof"11-25-2015"&sel=Name,EndDate,State,Workitems.ToDo.@Sum

but could only get present value but not the past ones.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are using the rest-1.v1/Data endpoint.  From this endpoint you will get the current state of assets in your VersionOne instance however, there is an attribute "Prior" which contains the previous state of a VersionOne asset (Timebox).  The most robust way to access historical data is though the rest-1.v1/Hist endpoint.  You can find details about Hist queries [here](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/Data_API/Learn_By_Example:_History_Queries/How_to_query_the_history_of_many_assets).

Using your query

`"base URL"/rest-1.v1/Hist/Timebox?where=State.Code='ACTV'&asof"2015-11-25T17:30:00.00"&sel=Name,EndDate,State,Workitems.ToDo.@Sum`

The [asof](http://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/Data_API/Learn_By_Example%3A_History_Queries/How_to_query_an_asset_%22as_of%22_a_specific_time) keyword will return the state of that Timebox at that instance in time. Observe the proper format of the date.