# Is there a way to get Total estimate, open estimate, closed estimate from versionone / digital.ai rest api for epic?

Tags: versionone

I am using the rest api end point "https://company hosted versionone/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=Name ...&where=Scope.ParentMeUp.Name='Project Name'..." to fetch all data of epic for a scope. 
I am looking to get 'Total Estimate', Closed Estimate, Open Estimate for all sub/children and under i.e sum of Estimates of all stories.
I am trying something like ".../rest-1.v1/Data/Epic?sel=SubsAndDown:PrimaryWorkItem.Estimate.@Sum" but its not working.
I have come across the estimate total at scope level - like this answer 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956826/how-do-i-use-the-version-one-api-to-get-project-and-sprint-burndown-charts/15231219#15231219' but i am looking for estimation total at Epic level
Any help appreciated!